# wsadmin script/command arguments to modify auth data entries

Tags: scripting, wsadmin

Can someone help me how i can update an authentication data entry using wsadmin  without logging into was console as i have too many data sources and doing them manually is a time taking procedure. Below is the far that i can get to. Not sure how to use the arguments. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
wsadmin>$AdminTask help modifyAuthDataEntry  
WASX8006I: Detailed help for command: modifyAuthDataEntry

Description: Modify an authentication data entry

Target object:   None

Arguments:
  securityDomainName - Name used to uniquely identify the security domain.
  *alias - The alias of the auth data.
  user - The username of the auth data.
  password - The password of the auth data.
  description - The description of the auth data.

Steps:
  None

wsadmin>
```

Comment: If you know how to use the admin console to do a given action, you can use [command assistance](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0812_rhodes/0812_rhodes.html) to display the equivalent scripting command.

Comment: Scott, i have the command assistance enabled already and all it is giving me is AdminTask.listAuthDataEntries() which is not helpful in my case. I'm trying to update the password and want to know the arguments that i need to pass and how i need to pass them . thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Modify authData with:

```
AdminTask.modifyAuthDataEntry('[-alias myAlias -user myUser -password myPassword -description "my alias description" ]')
```

In general, to learn the wsadmin command for a given Admin Console operation which you know how to perform, you can use the [command assistance](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0812_rhodes/0812_rhodes.html) function to capture the equivalent last wsadmin scripting command.

Comment: Scott, thank you and this command works. The next big challenge that i'm seeing is how can i automate this activity as we have about 15 auth aliases that we need to change passwords for. Also i don't want this exact line to be put in a  py file and run it as i have to put the passwords in that file which is not a best practice. We have an utility/script that generates random passwords and i need to take that command output (which is a password basically ), as a variable and put it in the -password field in the above admintask.

Comment: For string manipulation (e.g. propagating the passwords) and looping you can use standard Python constructs.  E.g. `cmdStr = .... ` ,  then `AdminTask.modifyAuthDataEntry(cmdStr)`, then `AdminConfig.save()`.

Comment: Avin, do you want to set the same password for all 15 auth aliases?

Comment: M I P, No, its a different password for each user

Comment: Scott, also can i pass the objects to wsadmin in a single command ? for example ./wsadmin.sh -lang jython  -c 'AdminTask.modifyAuthDataEntry('[-alias testone -user testone -password password1 ]');AdminConfig.save()' ... i'm getting an error if i do this. is there any way i can pass these two commands in one line

Comment: @avin - you could do   `./wsadmin.sh -lang jython -c "AdminTask.modifyAuthDataEntry('[-alias  testone -user testone -password password1]');  print AdminConfig.save()"`     to do this as a one-liner.    This lets you mix single quotes and double quotes in a single command.   I'd recommend you save this into a file and execution via the `wsadmin  -f` option, though...  it gives you even more flexibility plus you can save the command for next time.

Comment: Also, note that my last comment illustrates my point that your issues now are more generic Python/shell string manipulation questions.     There's nothing special you need to know about this particular wsadmin command.